# Creating a form in play by binding from request

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm building a web application in play and I'm quite new to play framework. I have a form that looks something like this:

```java
class ComplexForm {
    List<Person> persons;
}

class Person {
    String name;
    String email;
}
```

I want to pass an array of complexForms in the request where content-type has to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I cannot change it to `application/json` because of few other dependencies. I'm passing the data something like this:

`persons[0][name]=name&person[0][email]=email&person[1][name]=name2&person[1][email]=email2`

But when I do:

```
Form.form(ComplexForm.class).bindFromRequest().get()
```

I get an error:

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: persons[0][name] is neither an array nor a list nor a map.

How exactly do I bind this kind of a request to a nested object like above using play?

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `email` are properties of `person` thus your body should look as follows (no brackets):

```
persons[0].name=name&
person[0].email=email&
person[1].name=name2&
person[1].email=email2
```

Added new lines for readability.

Comment: I still get exception and this time it is this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value

Comment: Are you setting all required properties? Does your form has getters/setters?

Comment: Form has getters/setters. I haven't put any required constraint so I don't think it matters whether I pass all fields or not right?